# VBA - Excel SAP2000 API - Automation Error

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to start SAP2000 using VBA Excel but I get an error with the message: "Automation Error". The code is very simple:

```
Sub api()

Dim SapObject As Sap2000.SapObject
Set SapObject = New Sap2000.SapObject
SapObject.ApplicationStart

End Sub
```

This code should start SAP2000 but it does not.

SAP2000v14 is installed along with Office 2013. I have checked the tick box next to SAP2000 in Tools-References menu.

By the way, I can run SAP2000 using MATLAB.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `Dim SapObject As New Sap2000.SapObject` and omit the `Set` line?

Comment: Still I receive the same error.

Comment: try late binding, have you got reference to the SAP2000 API?

Comment: what is late binding? i have checked the tickbox next to SAP2000 in tools-references in VBA editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys. But I have sorted it out. In the compability options of SAP2000.exe, "run as admin" was selected. So I deselected it and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code for SAP 2000:

```
Option Explicit

  Dim SapObject As SAP2000.SapObject
  Dim ret As Long
  Dim Coordinates As Range
   Sub Sap2000_open()


  ' Create the Sap2000 object

      Set SapObject = CreateObject("SAP2000.SapObject")

      SapObject.ApplicationStart
      SapObject.SapModel.InitializeNewModel (kgf_m_C)
      ret = SapObject.SapModel.File.NewBlank

End Sub
```